# How do I fix bone orientation or align bones to global orientation?

Tags: bones, transform-orientation

So I imported an XPS model into Blender and the bones of the rig are all over the place, the face rig bones seem like they point along the normals of the mesh.
[image]

I want to make some custom controllers to make animation easier but the orientation of the bones is different from the global orientation.

[image]

So when I put a bone constraint on it to follow the controllers location transformation it moves along its own axis instead of the controllers or global axis.
What I'm looking for is a way to fix it so that the bone moves along the global axis, so I'll have to either change the bones' orientation without changing the bone (if that's even possible) or I need to align the bones' heads and tails with the global axis. Would also be cool if there was a way to do this quickly for multiple bones as there are a lot in this rig.
Any advice would be very much appreciated!

Comment: When retargeting rigs, often a layer of Empty objects is used to translate between the different alignments of the control and deformation bones. For example, if the control bone is aligned horizontally but the deformation bone is aligned vertically then add an Empty, rotate it by 90°, and create a parent-child hierarchy like this *control bone -> Empty -> deform bone*. The deformation bone is not really a child of the Empty but copies its transformation by a bone constraint. An Empty can be a child of a bone (Pose mode). With so many bones a script would be helpful to create the Empties.

Comment: @Blunder Hm I'm not sure what you mean, I tried parenting a bone to an Empty but it didn't work, can't find the Control Bone option. What menu is that located in? Or does it have to be a special sort of empty that's part of the rig somehow? Is there maybe a tutorial you could recommend that shows this? Thx for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution to this problem: I made a new bone without any weight and with normal axis orientation and then parented the existing bones to that so now I can use it as a controller to move the existing bones along the normal axes. Alternatively you can also make a new bone and then give the Child of bone constraint to the existing bones to let the new bone control them.